# Is $(document.body) and document.body the same? Cleaning garbage and binding in class? - MooTools 1.3

Tags: javascript, binding, garbage-collection, mootools, declaration

I am building a MooTools class and I have this in my initialize function:

```
this.css = null;

window.addEvent('domready', function(){

    this.document = $(document);
    this.body = $(document.body);
    this.head = $(document.head);

}.bind(this));
```

Ok and now to the questions ...
Should I declare this.css = null or any other empty variable in the init:

```
this.css = null; // Maybe this.css = '' - empty string?
```

Next thing is about window and document ... Should I put it into $() or not because it works both way, so I just want to know which way is preferred? So to summarize:

```
window.addEvent() // or should I use $(window).addEvent()
this.document = $(document) // or this.document = document
this.body = $(document.body) // or this.body = document.body
```

I stored these values into object to avoid multiple DOM queries, is this ok? Or would it be better to call $(selector) / $$(selector) every time?

Two more things left ... About binding ... Is it ok to use .bind(this) every time or would it be better to use .bind(this.myDiv) and use it inside function as eg.: this.setStyle(...); instead of this.myDiv.setStyle(...)

```
(function(){
  this.setStyle('overflow-y', 'visible');
 }.bind(this.body)).delay(100);
```

or

```
(function(){
  this.body.setStyle('overflow-y', 'visible');
 }.bind(this)).delay(100);
```

And the last thing is about garbage collection ... Do I have to garbage myself and how to do it (as far as I know MooTools does it on its own on unload). The confusing part is that I found function in MT docs:

```
myElement.destroy();
```

They say: Empties an Element of all its children, removes and garbages the Element. Useful to clear memory before the pageUnload.

So I have to garbage on my own? How to do that? When to use .destroy()? I am working on a huge project and I notice that IE gets slow over multiple executions of the script (so how to handle that? probably some cleaning needed, memory leaks?).

Comment: Nice question! Btw, are you still using MooTools?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pff, this is a bit long.

first, initial variables. `this.css = null`... the only time i'd set 'empty' variables are: typecast; when it's a property of an object i may reference and don't want undefined; when it's a string i will concatenate with or a number i will incre/decrement; null is not really useful at this point.

a common / good practice when writing a mootools class is to use the Options class as a mixin. this allows you to set default options object with your default settings that can be overridden upon instantiation. similarly, `Object.merge({ var: val}, useroptions);` can override a default val if supplied.

now, iirc, there are times when you'd have to use `$(document.body)` and it's not because document.body does not work, it's because applying `$()` also applies Element prototypes in IE (since Element prototype is not extended there, the methods are applied to the elements directly instead, which happens when you $ them). Also, $ assigns an internal UID of the target element and allows for element storage to be used for that element. I don't see a point to using `$(document)` or `$(window)` - they are 'extended' as much as needed by default. In any case, even in IE, you only need to `$(something)` the one time and can continue using it as just 'something' afterwards. check my `document.getElementById("foo").method()` example - you can just run `$("foo");` on it's own and then try `document.getElementById("foo").method()` again - it will work in IE too.

```
window.addEvent(); // is fine. 
document.body.adopt(new Element("div")); // not fine in IE.
new Element("div").inject(document.body); // fine.
```

and on their own:

```
$(document.body).adopt(new Element("div")); // fine.
document.body.adopt(new Element("span")); // now fine, after first $.
```

see this in ie8: http://www.jsfiddle.net/AePzD/1/ - first attempt to set the background fails but the second one works. subsequently, `document.body.methods()` calls are going to work fine.

http://www.jsfiddle.net/AePzD/2/ - this shows how the element (which $ also returns) can have methods in webkit/mozilla and not in trident. however, replace that with $("foo") and it will start working. rule of thumb: $ elements you don't dynamically create before applying methods to them.

storing selectors can be a *good* performance practice, for sure. but it can also fill your scope chain with many variables so be careful. if you will use a selector two or more times, it's good to cache it. failing to do so is not a drama, selector engines like sizzle and slick are so fast these days it does not matter (unless you are animating at the time and it impacts your FPS).

as for binding, whichever way you like.

keep in mind delay has a second argument, BIND:

```
(function(){
      this.setStyle('background', 'blue');
 }).delay(100, $("foo"));
```

so do quite a few functions. this particular bind is not very useful but in a class, you may want to do

```
(function(){
      this.element.setStyle('background', 'blue');
      this.someMethod();
 }).delay(100, this));
```

GC. mootools does it's own GC, sure. however, .destroy is a very good practice, imo. if you don't need something in the DOM, use element.dispose(). if you won't attach it to the DOM again, use .destroy() - removes all child nodes and cleans up. more memory \o/

advice on IE... dodgy. you can use drip if you can to trace memory leaks, there are things like dynatrace that can be very good in profiling. in terms of practices... make sure you don't use inline js, you always clean up what you don't need (events, elements) and generally, be careful, esp when you are stacking up events and dealing with ajax (bring new elements that need events - consider event delegation instead...). use fewer dom nodes - also helps...

Comment: Great! Thanks for such a fast answer, you have well explained and many things are clear now ...

Comment: what is great is that you are taking the time to find out the best practices--something that a lot of people neglect to do. I only hope I can answer well enough. read the about mootools wiki here and the blogs linked for more insights

Comment: Thanks ... Which blogs have you linked? And one more thing ... If I use $(document.body) for the first time and then just refer to it as document.body, should I store it to a variable for eg.: this.body? Or is it always referencing back to $(document.body) and I could just use document.body?

Comment: you don't need to do this.body = $(document.body); and it won't refer to same but to result. no need to store it, it does a single property lookup for body. a local reference can help, but if its a class property, like `this.body`, it won't be faster as a lookup than `document.body`. in fact, I rarely even need to $(document.body) as I tend not to apply methods to it but pass it on as an argument to methods, like `element.inject(document.body)`. element searches are usually done via `document.getElements("selector")` so no need for body. to extend it all you need is this: `$(document.body);`

Comment: the last bit, it's a one-off operation. once body inherits the mootools element prototypes, it has them and you don't need to use the selector $ on it anymore. as for blogs, have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mootools/info - i recommend the ryan florence articles on creating mootools plugins / classes. very very handy.